# is it possible to change distros within your current distro without losing data

Tags: linux, kde, parrot-os

the title says it all I want to change my distro to parrot home KDE I'm currently running Kubuntu from the command line possibly as that's the most convient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no you cannot change Linux distributions.

It is possible to move from one flavor of distro to another, like from Kubuntu to Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu Cinnamon, etc.

It might be possible to resize your current install and then install Parrot Linux in the free space.  Then you could mount your old partitions and/or volumes.

However, it will be far easier to simply back up your data and install Parrot Linux from scratch.  Then restore your data back to the new OS.

Comment: thanks I have already backed up and I'm moving today thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Linux is flexible but not that flexible.
If you want to mix distributions you want [Bedrock Linux](https://bedrocklinux.org/)

Comment: thanks I haven't heard if bedrock before I'll get a virtual machine of it but I have backed up mu disc and I'm moving today

Comment: If you don't have much Linux experience or special needs I think you are better of using a regular distribution. Especially if it is your main machine.  I use Debian stable on my main computer but started out using Ubuntu, since drivers etc. is easier. Debian is more stable long term though, but *might* require a little more work.